# Sending json in body for API post tests

Tags: c#, rest

I'm trying to send json  code in a body for a POST api test.  As shown below.
Problem is I get errors due to the square brackets, compiler says ') expected' and '; expected'.
How can I fix this?

```
JObject jObjectbody = new JObject();
jObjectbody.Add("x": ["xxxxx8P22"]);
jObjectbody.Add("verifiedPriceDate", "2020-02-28");

request.AddParameter("application/json; jObjectbody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

In postman the request works fine, but in the body I need to pass exactly the below:
[image]

Comment: square bracket is required in value? try "["xxxxx8P22"]" i.e. surround with double quotation.

Comment: yes square bracket is required in the value, tried doing above but get 'syntax error , expected' error

Comment: try this - "[\"xxxxx8P22\"]"

Comment: same error recieved

Comment: Please correct code.  it should be - request.AddParameter("application/json", jObjectbody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

Comment: yes thanks, i did that already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use escape characters. For C# you can write like this:

```
string jsonData = "\"x\": [xxxxP82]";
```